# problema con una consulta de MySql where in, el parámetro que se envían se convierten en una cadena

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs, base-de-datos, typescript

Buenas tengo un procedimiento almacenado que realiza una consulta usando múltiples valores IN
cuando se ejecuta de forma normal en el IN **(1,6,7,8,9,15,58,66,71,99,105,668,5864)** si funciona. pero este valor se genera según consulta de un formulario.

**fragmento de código**

```
                    let zz
                    a.c.filter(nc => {
                        zz += nc.a_c + ','
                    }) 
                    
                    // 1,6,7,8,9,15,58,66,71,99,105,668,5864


                    z.query("CALL Tc_data_retransmision(?,?,?)", [zz.slice(0, -1).replace('undefined', ''), '2021-02-19 00:00:00', '2021-02-19 00:04:00'], (err, result) =>{
                        if (err) {
                            //return e(y(err))
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            z.end()
                            console.log(result[0])
                            //return e(JSON.stringify(x(result[0][0], a.d)))
                        }
                    })
```

al ejecutarlo como tal, me devuelve solo el resultado del primer digito de la cadena, **1** en el procedimiento almacenado también intente usar un remplace, pero no funciona, **replace(a, "'", "")**

**fragmento de código**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`stackoverflow`@`999.999.999.999` PROCEDURE `procedure_stackoverflow`(IN a VARCHAR(100), IN b VARCHAR(20), IN c VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
        SELECT 
            B.stackoverflow1,       
            B.stackoverflow2,
            B.stackoverflow3,
            ...
        FROM 
            stackoverflowdata.stackoverflowtable B
        WHERE 
            
            B.stackoverflow_id IN(replace(a, "'", ""))
            AND B.stackoverflow_datetime BETWEEN b AND c;
    END$$
```

por favor alguna idea para solucionar este predicamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dado que MySQL no tiene una función nativa que permita explotar un string para generar un array, se me ocurren dos soluciones.

Tenemos tu string de ids concatenados `1,6,7,8,9,15,58,66,71,99,105,668,5864`, que voy a poner en una variable. También lo usaré para crear una segunda variable que es lo mismo pero envuelto en corchetes:

```
SET @ids_concatenados:='1,6,7,8,9,15,58,66,71,99,105,668,5864',
    @ids_json_array:=concat('[',@ids_concatenados,']');

SELECT @ids_concatenados, @ids_json_array
```

| @ids_concatenados | @ids_json_array |
| --- | --- |
| 1,6,7,8,9,15,58,66,71,99,105,668,5864 | [1,6,7,8,9,15,58,66,71,99,105,668,5864] |

Puedes aprovechar el casteo implícito que ocurre al usar [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM stackoverflowtable
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(stackoverflow_id, @ids_concatenados)
```

(pese a que `stackoverflow_id` no es un string, MySQL es permisivo al respecto).

O puedes usar una función JSON dependiendo de tu versión de MySQL. En la 5.7 serviría usar [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains), que tratará nuestra variable `@ids_json_array` como un array de números:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM stackoverflowtable
 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(@ids_json_array, stackoverflow_id)
```

Comment: exelente lógica voy a probarla.

Comment: bien jugado doctor, golazo, [enlace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztxq6Rby8ho)